# Laravel: Field 'remember_me' doesn't have a default value

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am creating a CMS Application where a user, of course, needs to register or login first.

But I got a problem when sending the data to the database. It says `'Field 'remember_me' doesn't have a default value'`.

I am unable to find why it expects a default value since I am sending the remember_me data i.e. checked=>1 and unchecked=>0! I am using Javascript for this!

`RegisterController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Authentication;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index() {
        return view('auth.register');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create() {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request) {
        $user = User::create($request->all());

        return redirect('/');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id) {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id) {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id) {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id) {
        //
    }
}
```

register.blade.php

```
@extends('master')

@section('title')
  Register - CMS APP
@endsection

@section('styles')
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/auth.css') }}">
@endsection

@section('register')
  <form class="form-signin" method="post" accept-charset="utf8" action="/register">
    @csrf
    <img class="mb-4" src="http://logo.kenh.net/logo/bootstrap-4.svg.png" alt="" width="72" height="72">
    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please Register</h1>
    <label for="inputFirstName" class="sr-only">First Name</label>
    <input name="fname" type="string" id="inputFirstName" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" required autofocus>
    <label for="inputLastName" class="sr-only">Last Name</label>
    <input name="lname" type="string" id="inputLastName" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" required autofocus>
    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
    <input name="email" type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input name="password" type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <div class="checkbox mb-3">
      <label>
        <input name="remember_me" id="rememMe" type="checkbox" value="0"> Remember me
      </label>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit">Register</button>
    <br>
    <a href="/login" class="btn btn-primary">Login</a>
  </form>
@endsection

<script>
  window.onload = () => {
    let rememberMe = document.getElementById('rememMe');

    rememberMe.onclick = () => {
      if(rememberMe.checked) {
        rememberMe.value = 1;
      }else {
        rememberMe.value = 0;
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Routes

```
Route::resource('register', 'Authentication\RegisterController')->only([
    'index', 'store'
]);
```

Migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('role_id')->default(2);
            $table->integer('is_active')->default(1);
            $table->integer('remember_me');
            $table->string('fname');
            $table->string('lname');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Please help me fix it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**When a checkbox is checked in a form it gives the value of `on`, not `1`.** The field in your database is storing an `integer` value, you should really be using a `boolean`. This way Eloquent will accept and store values from `on`, `off` and input them as `1` or `0`.

The prevent this error in future you should add a default value to your field, and store it as a boolean.

Create a new migration.

`php artisan make:migration add_default_remember_me_to_users`

Then in the migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function($table) {
        // Change field to boolean and define a default value
        $table->boolean('remember_me')->default(0)->change();
    });
}

public function down()
{
    Schema::table('users', function($table) {
        $table->integer('remember_me')->change();
    });

}
```

Then run your migration:

`php artisan migrate`

and you should be good to go!

Comment: No worries ! :)

Answer (score 0):

i think the value of checked box should be 1 because when you submit it'll be 0 even if it's checked

`<input name="remember_me" id="rememMe" type="checkbox" value="1">`

and to make sure error won't ever happen again you can do this in your controller

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $request['remember_me'] = $request['remember_me'] ? 1 : 0;
    $user = User::create($request->all());

    return redirect('/');
}
```

hope this helps